# Cannot scrapy german website using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I am doing web scraping using `Scrapy`, successfully created a spider which will crawl the full website including the internal links having same domain, I have used Link Extractor to achieve this. This scraping works successfully for English websites but when I try to **scrape** German website it doesn't work, callback `function parse_item()` doesn't gets called. if I change `parse_item()` to `parse()` then German website domain URL is scraped but not the internal links. How do I fix this?

Below is my code:

```
class WebSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'WebSpider'
    
     #init function
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         #code to accept domain url
         
        WebSpider.rules = [
                Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
            ]

        super(WebSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs

     def parse_item(self, response):
         #Call back function to work with response
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when running the script? Or it just runs without failing but doesn't do what you expected it to? If there are any errors, please edit your question and add them in

Comment: no i don't get any errors and i have also tried putting try catch block to see if any error occurs but no errors in terminal, it runs successfully.

Comment: "Below is my code" -- is that really all of it? I can't run this to verify your results.

Comment: @usr2564301 that is just the structure of the code which i presented, init() method gives the domain url for start_urls and sets language as german thats it, just wanted to know why parse_item() method is not called for german websites.